# C# checkedlistbox mouse enter/leave error

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mouseevent, checkedlistbox

I want my checkedlistbox to expand to a certain size when the mouse enters and then go back to a its original size after mouse leaves. Below is the code is have. However, I receive an error when i have another program selected and my mouse goes over the checkedlistbox while the application is not active.

Any suggestions on how to fix?

```
    private void checkedListBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Search.ActiveForm.Height = 552;
        checkedListBox1.Height = 130;


    }

    private void checkedListBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Search.ActiveForm.Height = 452;
            checkedListBox1.Height = 34;}
```

Error Code - Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: What is `Search`? any relationship with `checkedListBox1`? What's the actual form do you want to change `Height`?

Comment: what is `Search.ActiveForm`?, you could check if the form is top most before changing height

Comment: Sry, Search is the name of the application. Search.cs.

Comment: `Search` is a `Form` right?

Comment: Have you tried with `this.Height = 552` instead of `Search.ActiveForm.Height = 552;`?

Comment: Search is the name of the Form.

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria Thats perfect! That worked great!! Awesome! Thanks everyone for their quick help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
private void checkedListBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  checkedListBox1.Size = new Size(Width,Height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This of course would work so that no exception is thrown, but I hope it's also what you want:

```
private void checkedListBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Search.ActiveForm == null) return;
    Search.ActiveForm.Height = 552;
    checkedListBox1.Height = 130;
}

private void checkedListBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Search.ActiveForm == null) return;
    Search.ActiveForm.Height = 452;
    checkedListBox1.Height = 34;
 }
```